# How to specify Proxy Pass in kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have my assets on s3 and my service is deployed on kubernetes. Is it possible to define proxy pass in nginx-ingress. My current nginx proxy_pass assets to s3 and I want to replicate in kubernetes.

```
location /assets/ {
          proxy_pass https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com;
   }
```

I tried this but its not working

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location /assets/ {
              proxy_pass https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/assets/;
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use service of type ExternalName here like that:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: s3-ap-south
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: s3-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: YOUR_HOSTNAME
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: s3-ap-south
          servicePort: 443
```

Comment: yes this will work I know, but by question is why proxy_pass doesn't work?

Comment: you can actually look at generated Nginx config inside of Nginx-ingress-controller pod. I can guess config snippet you provide is included into already existing location stanza.

Comment: ohh I understand that means already included location hash priority over the snippet I have written.

Comment: that means we can never able to use proxy_pass in snippet because location block will always be there introduced by spec.rules.host.paths

Answer (score 3):

You can use `proxy_pass` in Ingress as in normal Nginx.

So if you have some local or public HTTP/HTTPS service which is outside of Kubernetes cluster and you want to serve this through Ingress, you just need this:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: owncloud
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~ "^/(.*)" {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.250.100:8260;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: owncloud.example.com
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - owncloud.example.com
    secretName: owncloud-example-tls
```

- Remove `ssl`, `secure`, `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `tls` bits if you don't need HTTPS
- You can add more location blocks such as `~ "^/api/(.*)"` so it works as normal Nginx
- It will retain domain name so for instance in browser's address bar you will have original one. In case you need to do a full redirect, start experimenting with `proxy_set_header Host $host;` removal

Hope that helps someone