# Kubernetes ingress-nginx rewrite without changing browser url

Tags: url, kubernetes, url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We want to load **example.xyz.com** in **site.abc.com**. The best way is to redirect/rewrite all the requests from **site.abc.com** to **example.xyz.com**. However, we don't want the browser URL to be changed. [From this similar SO problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/927820/nginx-rewrite-url-without-changing-browser-address) we understand that we need an Nginx location config as below

```
server {
    servername site.abc.com;
    listen        80;
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    location / {                  
        proxy_pass  http://example.xyz.com;
        rewrite /(.*)$ /$1 break;
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to create a similar rule in [Kubernetes ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) as it adds proxy_pass for each rule, which prevents us from adding proxy_pass config in `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet:` annotation.

Also providing `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: http://example.xyz.com/$1` annotation in ingress as below, redirects to **example.xyz.com** instead of loading **example.xyz.com** in **site.abc.com**.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: http://example.xyz.com/$1
  name: url-rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: site.abc.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

How can we load **example.xyz.com** in **site.abc.com** without any change in browser URL using ingress-nginx in this case?

Comment: Hello @Mani. Have you happened to see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60354450/11560878)?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor i tried it and it is working. Thanks.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor any thoughts on SSL redirection issue as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Hello @Mani. Glad it helped. As for the SSL redirection, I recommend asking a separate question for clarity sake. It will be easier for the community to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60354450/6663095) as a reference, pointed out by [@WytrzymałyWiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11560878/wytrzyma%C5%82y-wiktor) I was able to make changes and it worked.
Here is the updated ingress file.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~ "^/(.*)" {
        proxy_pass http://example.xyz.com;
        rewrite /(.*)$ /$1 break;
      }
  name: url-rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: site.abc.com
```

One problem though here in making SSL redirect work. In some cases the target(**http://example.xyz.com**) will return `302 /some/other/path` in such cases http://site.abc.com gets redirected as http://site.abc.com/some/other/path. Not sure how to make it to redirect as https://site.abc.com/some/other/path.
Setting `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"` doesn't seem to work.

Adding this as an answer for documentation, As it will be helpful for people with a similar problem. Not a possible duplicate as the referenced solution addresses on adding `proxy_pass` whereas this, addresses URL rewrite without changing browser URL.